# Unable to use Common Table Expressions in Postgres Crosstab Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table, temp-tables

I'm trying to use perform a pivot operation on some data using Postgres' `tablefunc` extension's `CROSSTAB` function. The data needs to undergo some transformations first, which I perform in some *common table expressions*.

However, it appears `CROSSTAB` can't see the results of those expressions.

For example, this query sourcing data from a *temporary table* works fine:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
  temporary_table
    (name, category, category_value)
ON COMMIT DROP
AS (
  VALUES
    ('A',  'foo',    1             ),
    ('A',  'bar',    2             ),
    ('B',  'foo',    3             ),
    ('B',  'bar',    4             )
);

SELECT * FROM
  CROSSTAB(
    'SELECT * FROM temporary_table',
    $$
      VALUES
        ('foo'),
        ('bar')
    $$
  ) AS (
    name TEXT,
    foo  INT,
    bar  INT
  );
```

and, as expected, produces the following output:

| name | foo | bar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 4 |

But the same query, this time using *common table expressions* doesn't run:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;
WITH
  common_table
    (name, category, category_value)
AS (
  VALUES
    ('A',  'foo',    1             ),
    ('A',  'bar',    2             ),
    ('B',  'foo',    3             ),
    ('B',  'bar',    4             )
)
SELECT * FROM
  CROSSTAB(
    'SELECT * FROM common_table',
    $$
      VALUES
        ('foo'),
        ('bar')
    $$
  ) AS (
    name TEXT,
    foo  INT,
    bar  INT
  )
```

and produces the following error:

```
ERROR:  relation "common_table" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM common_table
                      ^
QUERY:  SELECT * FROM common_table

********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "common_table" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
```

I take it this means the text query `SELECT * FROM common_table` runs in some sort of different context. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 15):

All you need to do is move your `CTE` inside the string as the first argument to `crosstab(text, text)` function just like you did with the select statement. It will be parsed and executed properly. This is because you provide full SQL statement that produces the source set in first argument.

You need to double your quotation marks inside the string or use dollar-quoting `$$` just like you did with the second argument and I did below:

```
SELECT * FROM
  CROSSTAB(
    $$
    WITH common_table(name, category, category_value) AS (
      VALUES
        ('A',  'foo',    1             ),
        ('A',  'bar',    2             ),
        ('B',  'foo',    3             ),
        ('B',  'bar',    4             )
    )
    SELECT * FROM common_table $$,
    $$
      VALUES
        ('foo'),
        ('bar')
    $$
  ) AS (
    name TEXT,
    foo  INT,
    bar  INT
  );
```

Result

```
 name | foo | bar
------+-----+-----
 A    |   1 |   2
 B    |   3 |   4
```

Comment: Any ideas on some alternate approaches? I use a series of CTEs in some of my queries, and the ability to use a cte or temp table in a CROSSTAB would be great.

Comment: You can use as many CTEs as a source to crosstab as you like. They are all a part of one statement, in the end. If you need further assistance and find your case to be different, make sure to search for the solution. When out of luck, please post a separate question on StackOverflow :)

Comment: This works great, thanks. Its a shame you cant reuse your CTE when using the category_sql version of crosstab(). But I can always dump it into a table somewhere.